# Access images in public_html from a subdirectory Admin - Laravel

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-blade, shared-hosting, intervention

I am using shared hosting (cPanel) to host my website (Developed in Laravel 5.4). I have another instance of Laravel 5.4 as an **admin** which is within the public_html folder. Both work fine as a separate instances but I can't upload/view/delete images through admin which is 1 step deeper in public_html folder.

**Current directory structure**

```
/root
/- .cpanel
/- examplewebsite.com (laravel instance)
/- public_html
   /- img
   /- js
   /- css
   /- admin (laravel instance)
```

So when I am in examplewebsite.com and I use **asset("/img/some_image.jpg")** it works fine `<img src="http://examplewebsite.com/img/sample.jpg">` and point to the **img** folder with in public_html but for **admin panel** it points **img** folder with in the admin panel so it becomes `<img src="http://examplewebsite.com/admin/img/sample.jpg">` (which is correct) but is there a way or best practice through which I can access images in public_html from **admin** (laravel instance).

PS: There are similar questions but I couldn't find the answer. Please advice, thanks in advance

Comment: A plain old `<img src="/img/some_image.jpg">` should work fine. Since your `admin` instance doesn't know of the existence of the other Laravel install, `asset` isn't going to work. (In general, it's better to have everything be in the same Laravel install. There's not typically a reason to separate it like this - you can separate everything *within* a single install using namespacing etc..)

Comment: It's still not working. It would add /admin/ 

<img src="http://examplewebsite.com/admin/img/sample.jpg">.